# ¿porque aunque puse un margin 0 en el body, mi lista deja un borde con el h1?

Tags: html, css

Este es un proyecto que estoy empezando a hacer para aprender a usar html y css, pero me sale este inconveniente y no se como arreglarlo.

si se preguntan que hay en las paginas que estan en el codigo no son nada, solo estan para acordarme que tengo que hacerlas.

```css
body{
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica ;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #b42a06;
    text-align: center;
}
.lista{
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #590d0d;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nimuinitantan Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>tienda</h1>
    <nav class="lista">
        <ul>
            <il><a href="paginas/Inicio.html">Inicio</a></il>
            <il><a href="paginas/Series.html">Series</a></il>
            <il><a href="paginas/Productos.html">Productos</a></il>
            <il><a href="paginas/Redes.html">Redes</a></il>
            <il><a href="paginas/FaQ.html">FaQ</a></il>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si quieres aprender desarrollo web, aprende a utilizar las herramientas de desarrollador. Si las abres y accedes a la parte de elementos puedes inspeccionar visualmente cada elemento y ahí verás que tu `<ul>` tiene un margin de 16px arriba y abajo (técnicamente, tiene `1rem` pero con tamaño de fuente normal eso son 16px :) ). Los navegadores aplican ciertos estilos por defecto para mejorar la legibilidad (o para tocar los cajones, no sé...)

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar, se puede agregar un `display: flex` (lo que más recomiendo, para acomodar los items a gusto sin problemas: el `ul` o algún otro div).

El `flex` es para acomodar su contenido de forma horizontal.

En el **CSS** agregué `*` lo cual es universal (estilo para todo los componentes).
Agregué estilo para el `ul` y `li`.

También arregle las etiquetas `li` que pusiste il, y no `li`.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica ;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #b42a06;
    text-align: center;
}

.lista{
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0;*/
    background-color: #590d0d;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%
}

li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nimuinitantan Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>tienda</h1>
    <nav class="lista">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="paginas/Inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/Series.html">Series</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/Productos.html">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/Redes.html">Redes</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/FaQ.html">FaQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```